# An article not presented in conference but published in conference special issue

Tags: publications, ethics, conference, special-issue

Although an article was not presented at the conference, this article published in the conference special issue of a journal after reviewing and editorial process. Considering whether the authors attended the conference or not, is there an ethical problem in this case?

Comment: Possibly field dependent. [One of my most used conference proceedings on my bookshelves](https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-42) says in the *Introduction* on p. ix "Many mathematicians who did not present papers in that session have also contributed papers to this volume", and I don't recall ever seeing anyone anywhere making the distinction, in a citation to any of these papers, between whether or not the person attended the conference. In fact, the only way I know to determine this is from p. 257 of the [April 1982 Notices AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/198204/198204FullIssue.pdf).

Comment: This sort of thing often happens. Authors of such articles might be people who were invited to speak at the conference but declined the invitation.   Or they might have planned to speak but were prevented from doing so because of health problems, coronavirus travel restrictions, visa issues, etc.  And there are probably other relevant situations that I'm not thinking of right now.